# Problems using a SELECT tag in a custom element with a CONTENT tag

Tags: javascript, shadow-dom, custom-element, html5-template

[Here's the jsfiddle showing the behavior](http://jsfiddle.net/cyrxpbpj/).

I expected to be able to pull in the `option` elements into the insertion point in the Shadow DOM but, as the `select` is empty, I don't think that's happening. The Chrome inspector isn't super helpful with insertion points anyway but I've verified that my browser works when doing other insertion point stuff, e.g. anything other than inserting `option` elements into a `select`.

I define a custom element like so:

```
var CatpantsProto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

CatpantsProto.createdCallback = function(e) {
  var shadow = this.createShadowRoot();
  var t = document.getElementById('guy');
  var clone = document.importNode(t.content, true);
  shadow.appendChild(clone);
};

document.registerElement('cat-pants', {
  prototype: CatpantsProto
});
```

Here is the `#guy` template:

```
<template id="guy">
  <span>Before</span>
  <select>
    <content></content>
  </select>
  <span>After</span>
</template>
```

Here is the usage:

```
<cat-pants>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</cat-pants>
```

Again, I expected those `option` elements to be inserted into the `select` in the Shadow DOM but they don't show up when I open the dropdown.

I thought maybe "deriving" from `HTMLElement` was the problem, but it doesn't work if I implement `HTMLSelectElement` either.

I also experimented with not using a template and modifying the `shadow`'s `innerHTML` directly but that didn't work either.

My current thinking is that `option` elements just aren't valid outside of `select`s, `datalist`s, or `optgroup`s and the browser is throwing some kind of fit but not telling me about it.

I'm at a loss and will probably work around this by creating a second `item` element placeholder that gets transformed into `option` elements in my `createdCallback`. Argh.

Comment: I got something working: I make a <datalist> element that's a sibling of my custom element. The custom element gets the id of the <datalist> and queries its children <option> elements and adds them to the interal <select>. Not optimal compared to making it work like a native <select>.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to create a Shadow Root with that type of element, because the browser itself creates its own (user-agent) shadow DOM to display a select control.

If so you'll get the following error:

> Failed to execute 'createShadowRoot' on 'Element': Author-created
>   shadow roots are disabled for this element.

Instead you should extend the `<select>` element itself, or copy the `<option>s`  directy with Javascript (not via the `<content>` way).